# como ejecutar una accion cuando un campo se quede vacio

Tags: c#

tengo dos textbox relacionados: sub-total y descuento , de manera tal que si el sub-total es mayor o igual a 500 el descuento sera igual 0.10 tengo el siguiente codigo pero cuando el textbox subtotal queda vacio el string queda en formato incorrecto.

```
private void txtsubtotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtsubtotal.Text) >= 500)
        {
            txtdescuento.Text = "0.10";
        }
        else
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(txtsubtotal.Text) <= 499)
            {
                txtdescuento.Text = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                if(txtsubtotal.Text=="")
                {
                    txtdescuento.Text = "0";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Supongo que es Winforms... en primera, ¿porqué usas textboxes para capturar números? hay otros controles que ya incluyen validación, como el numericupdown. En segunda, ¿porqué utilizas convert.toint32? ¿has pensado que pasa si el usuario escribe letras? si vas a udar textbox al menos mete algo de validación, usa int.tryparse en vez de convert.toint32. Es casi seguro que por eso te da formato incorrecto.

Comment: Para controlar esa regla de negocio debes evaluar como primera instancia si el textbox está vacío, caso contrario debes hacer las conversiones y cálculos correspondientes y no dejar que ocurra una excepción de un caso totalmente controlable para ejecutar la regla de negocio definida. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{
  if (Convert.ToInt32(txtsubtotal.Text) >= 500)
    {
        txtdescuento.Text = "0.10";
    }else{
        txtdescuento.Text = "0";
    }
}catch(Exeption ex){
    txtdescuento.Text = "0";
}
```

Intenta de esta forma ya que al dejar la caja de texto vacía se producirá una excepción y cuando eso suceda el descuento sera igual a 0 :)

Comment: gracias me funciono

Comment: En este caso el control de la regla de negocio es tan sencillo que no se justifica dejar que ocurra una excepción para hacer cero el descuento. Saludos.

Comment: bueno si tienes razón en lugar de esperar una excepción se  podría usar una condición de si la caja de texto es vacía  el descuento sea 0 :)